# If $x=(a+bt)e^{-nt}$, show that $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + 2n\frac{dx}{dt} +n^2x = 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Question : If $x=(a+bt)e^{-nt}$, show that $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + 2n\frac{dx}{dt} +n^2x = 0$

I got $\frac{dx}{dt}$
Then $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$ and plugged in these values

But at the end I got $$-n^2ae^{-nt} -n^2bte^{-nt} +n^2x$$

I don't know how to proceed further

---

How I proceeded with this

I simplified the bracket further $(x=ae^{-nt} + bte^{-nt})$

And solved for $\frac {dx} {dt}$ ( i got $\frac {dx} {dt}$ = $-nae^{-nt} - nbte^{-nt} + be^{-nt}$

And then solved for $\frac {d^2x} {dt^2}$

( i got $\frac {d^2x} {dt^2}$ = $n^2ae^{-nt} + n^2bte^-nt - nbe^{-nt} - nbe^{-nt})$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format both, your questions and your answers. Furthermore include your whole process therefore write down what you have got for the first and second dervative of $x$ so that we can see what you have done. Maybe it was a simple mistake while differentiating :)

Comment: $$y'=(-an-bnt+b)e^{-nt}$$
$$y''=n(an+bnt-2b)e^{-nt}$$

Comment: yes, they are..

Comment: Yup............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$xe^{nt}=at+b$$

**Method**$\#1:$

Differentiate wrt $x$  $$e^{nt}\left(nx+\dfrac{dx}{dt}\right)=a$$

Differentiate wrt $x$  $$e^{nt}n\left(nx+\dfrac{dx}{dt}\right)+e^{nt}\left(n\dfrac{dx}{dt}+\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}\right)=0$$

Now safely cancel $e^{nt}\ne0$

**Method**$\#2:$

[General Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) with $n=2$

$$\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}e^{nt}+\binom21\dfrac{dx}{dt}\dfrac{d(e^{nt})}{dt}+\binom22x\dfrac{d^2(e^{nt})}{dt^2}=0$$

Comment: How come in your mind the method one...

Comment: @Amit, Wanted to eliminate $a,b$

Comment: Why You wanted to eliminate a,b

Comment: @Amit, As $$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + 2n\frac{dx}{dt} +n^2x = 0$$ does not contain $a,b$

Comment: But sir we don't know whether y' and y'' contain a,b or not...

Comment: I mean we aren't sure

Comment: @Amit, The ultimate expression doesn't contain $a,b$ right? So, we explicitly don't need think of $y', y''$

Comment: Okay..."ultimate expression" you mean

Comment: $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + 2n\frac{dx}{dt} +n^2x = 0$

Comment: @Amit, Yes, u r right, see also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Second-order_case

Answer (score 0):

You can also show that
$$\exp(-nt)\,\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}\,\Big(\exp(nt)\,f(t)\Big)=\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}\,f(t)+2n\,\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\,f(t)+n^2\,f(t)$$
for all twice differentiable function $f$.  One way to see this is to write
$$\exp(-nt)\,\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\,\Big(\exp(nt)\,g(t)\Big)=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\,g(t)+n\,g(t)\,,$$
and
$$\exp(-nt)\,\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}\,\Big(\exp(nt)\,f(t)\Big)=\exp(-nt)\,\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\,\exp(nt)\,\Biggl(\exp(-nt)\,\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\,\Big(\exp(nt)\,f(t)\Big)\Biggr)\,.$$

Thus, $$\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}\,f(t)+2n\,\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\,f(t)+n^2\,f(t)=0$$ if and only if $\exp(nt)\,f(t)=a+bt$ for some constants $a$ and $b$, or equivalently, $$f(t)=(a+bt)\,\exp(-nt)\,.$$